# How to see this solution of a specific ODE by using addition formula of sine function?

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

**Question**
I recently read a [letter](http://eulerarchive.maa.org/correspondence/letters/OO0872.pdf) from Euler to Goldbach at the end of which Euler writes that the equation
$$
\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} = \frac{dy}{\sqrt{1-y^2}} 
$$
has integral
$$
y^2+x^2 = c^2 + 2xy \sqrt{1-c^2}.
$$
A friend told me that it is not hard to deduce this solution from the addition formula of sine:
$$
\sin(x+y) = \sin(x)\cos(y) + \cos(x)\sin(y).
$$
But I'm still confused.
Could anybody give me a hint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the integrals
$$
\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}=
\sin^{-1}x+c_1, \ \ \ \ \int\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-y^2}}=
\sin^{-1}y+c_2
$$
We get
$$
\sin^{-1}x=\sin^{-1}y+c_3$$
Thus:
$$x=\sin(\sin^{-1}y+c_3)=\sin(\sin^{-1}y)\cos c_3+\cos (\sin^{-1}y)\sin c_3\\=y\cos c_3+\sqrt{1-y^2}\sin c_3
$$
Or:
$$
(x-y\cos c_3)^2=\sin^2 c_3(1-y^2)
$$
$$
x^2-2xy\cos c_3+y^2\cos^2 c_3=\sin^2c_3-y^2\sin^2 c_3
$$
$$
x^2+y^2 =\sin^2c_3 + 2xy\cos c_3
$$
writing $\sin c_3=c$ we get:
$$
x^2+y^2=c^2+2xy\sqrt{1-c^2}
$$